# How to access object array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, array-filter

I am trying to filter it using array_filter

```
$time = (time() -10);

$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$datafilter = array_filter($data, function($obj)
        {
        return $obj->response->trade_offers_received->time_created > $time;
        });

echo $datafilter;
```

I am getting this notice: Trying to get property of non-object. So am doing something wrong. How can i filter this array to get only object where time_created > $time ?

This is my JSON data

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [trade_offers_received] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [tradeofferid] => 988832058
                            [accountid_other] => 212629269
                            [message] => 
                            [expiration_time] => 1455467839
                            [trade_offer_state] => 2
                            [items_to_give] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [appid] => 730
                                            [contextid] => 2
                                            [assetid] => 4974401193
                                            [classid] => 319730196
                                            [instanceid] => 188530139
                                            [amount] => 1
                                            [missing] => 
                                        )

                                )

                            [items_to_receive] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [appid] => 730
                                            [contextid] => 2
                                            [assetid] => 4981322842
                                            [classid] => 311848115
                                            [instanceid] => 188530139
                                            [amount] => 1
                                            [missing] => 
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [appid] => 730
                                            [contextid] => 2
                                            [assetid] => 3600963191
                                            [classid] => 350875311
                                            [instanceid] => 480085569
                                            [amount] => 1
                                            [missing] => 
                                        )
                                )

                            [is_our_offer] => 
                            [time_created] => 1454258239
                            [time_updated] => 1454258249
                            [from_real_time_trade] => 
                            [escrow_end_date] => 0
                            [confirmation_method] => 0
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [tradeofferid] => 988791916
                            [accountid_other] => 55306956
                            [message] => fv 0.1616 nice look
                            [expiration_time] => 1455466526
                            [trade_offer_state] => 2
                            [items_to_give] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [appid] => 730
                                            [contextid] => 2
                                            [assetid] => 4974401224
                                            [classid] => 311236182
                                            [instanceid] => 188530139
                                            [amount] => 1
                                            [missing] => 
                                        )
                                )
                            [items_to_receive] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [appid] => 730
                                            [contextid] => 2
                                            [assetid] => 4985509468
                                            [classid] => 310992880
                                            [instanceid] => 188530139
                                            [amount] => 1
                                            [missing] => 
                                        )
                                )

                            [is_our_offer] => 
                            [time_created] => 1454256926
                            [time_updated] => 1454256936
                            [from_real_time_trade] => 
                            [escrow_end_date] => 0
                            [confirmation_method] => 0
                        )
               )
        )
)
```

Comment: That is an array not an object. Use array notation

Comment: Looks like you need to iterate through the `trade_offers_received` object first, then access the `time_created` attribute inside each iteration.

Comment: @Defiant I tryed this also but its not working

Comment: If you want an object, remove the `TRUE` param from the `json_decode()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array.

Comment: Yea, of course it does, silly me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I am not sure what you will get if you do the `json_decode()` without the `TRUE` parameter that converts objects into arrays, we will stick with the array notation.

Also if you are only interested in data that exists at the `$data['response']['trade_offers_received']` level of this data structure, start your `array_filter` at that level.

But mainly as they are arrays, use the array notation and not the object notation and things will probably work

**More Importantly:**
You will also need to amend the closure code to pass the `$time` variable into the closure.

```
$time = (time() -10);

$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$datafilter = array_filter($data['response']['trade_offers_received'],
                              function($arr) use($time)
                              {
                                  return $arr['time_created'] > $time;
                              }
                           );

print_r( $datafilter );
```

Comment: Thanks , I ll try .  Basicly what am trying to do is found how many offers are there with time_created > time()-10. I am trying first to filter the array and than count it using count($datafilter['response']['trade_offers_received']) . Currently am getting this errors Undefined variable: time  and : Array to string conversion when am trying to echo $datafilter

Comment: To pass `$time` to the closure, you need to use the `USE($time)` syntax. Refresh the page as I missed that first time round

Comment: Thanks . I am still getting this Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\offer\funkcija.php on line 15. Line 15 is echo $datafilter;

Comment: Ok change that to a `print_r( $datafilter );` as its an array of course. I am really not paying attention today. Sorry

Comment: Nice , U are helped me a lot. Its working perfectly now. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

When you use `TRUE` as the second parameter of `json_decode`, it becomes an Array. If you want to get an object in return, remove the second parameter.

```
    $data = json_decode($json); //returns an object
    $arr  = json_decode($json); //returns an array
```

Comment: You might want to check that!

Comment: Its not particularly relevant to the question anyway as he wants an array so he can feed it into the `array_filter()` function. Not always a good idea to jump on comments and try to vampire them into answers!